# How does the temperature of the triple point of water depend on gravitational acceleration?

Tags: thermodynamics, order-of-magnitude

Suppose I do two experiments to find the triple point of water, one in zero-g and one on Earth.  On Earth, water in the liquid or solid phase has less gravitational potential per unit mass than water in the gas phase.  Therefore, the solid and liquid phases should be favored slightly more on Earth than in zero-g.

In a back-of-the-envelope calculation, how does the temperature of the triple-point of water depend on the gravitational acceleration and, if necessary, on the mass of water and volume and shape of container?

**Edit**
Let's say I have a box in zero-g.  The box is one meter on a side.  It has nothing in it but water.  Its temperature and pressure are just right so that it's at the triple point.  All the water and ice and steam are floating around the box because it's zero-g.

Now I turn on gravity.  The liquid water and ice fall to the bottom of the box, but the average height of the steam remains almost half a meter above the bottom of the box.  So when gravity got turned on, the potential energy of the ice and liquid water went down significantly, but the potential energy of the steam didn't.  Doesn't this mean that once gravity is turned on, water molecules would rather be part of the ice or liquid phase so that they can have lower energy?  Wouldn't we no longer be at the triple point?

Several people have posted saying the answer is "no".  I don't disbelieve that.  Maybe the answer is just "no".  I don't understand why the answer is no.  Answers such as "No, because gravity doesn't affect the triple point," or "No, because the triple point only depends on pressure and temperature" simply restate the answer "no" with more words.

Comment: The correction is likely vanishing except in the case of very strong fields as in the vicinity of a black hole. In that limit, however, this is an interesting and relevant question.

Comment: Why would the temperature depend on g and not the pressure? The triple point is a (p,T) point.

Comment: Changing the pressure (i.e. by adding gravity) means we move away from the triple point. What actually happens could depend on the initial density of the water in the box.  Note that this is not fixed by the pressure because at coexistence, different average densities can occur with the same pressure (simply different amounts of the coexisting phases).  Worth thinking about...

Comment: @Greg P Thanks.  On rereading your answer, I see that you got what I was asking more than I realized.

Comment: @Mark.  Well, I think we haven't actually answered the question.  We have only dissected the question ;-) I think it is still interesting, but before I can really answer there is something I am missing about what happens at the triple point...perhaps it would be interesting just to ask what happens during two-phase coexistence in a gravitational field.  Then move on to three-phase coexistence.

Comment: Let me add some specifics to the question.  In the presence of the g field, would we still see regions of the three phases? If so, how would they be arranged spatially? Does it depend on how much of the three phases we started with? Would we instead have only two coexisting phases, or perhaps just one? How can we figure out how much volume each phase takes up? In other words, how can we generalize the lever-rule/Maxwell construction to the case where there is a gravitational field?

Comment: I think a good starting point is to understand what happens to liquid-vapor coexistence: http://web.ist.utl.pt/berberan/data/79.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is perhaps similar to what mbq meant, but I will elaborate.
The T-p phase diagram of water tells us, for a given temperature and pressure, what phase we will get if we have a bunch of that substance.  If I apply different pressures to a bottle of water, I am moving around in the p-direction of the T-p plane.  I am not changing the pressure of the triple point of water, just changing the pressure of that particular bottle of water! Similarly, if a tank of water is in a gravitational field, it affects the pressure.  In fact, it leads to different pressures at different locations of the tank.  It could lead some parts of the tank to freeze, for example.  But it does not in any way change the triple point of water itself, which is an intrinsic property of that substance.  So I would say that the question is ill-posed.  It might be better to ask: what will happen to a tank of water at a given temperature and density if we now apply a gravitational field?

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is the correct answer. The questioner's demand for a more involved answer doesn't make one possible. It's a reasonable question to ask, but the answer is simply that the triple point of water is intrinsic to the material. It makes no more sense to ask for a better explanation that it does to ask why the temperature on Jupiter doesn't make my rice crispies taste better.

Comment: @Colin The triple point is not some fundamental thing.  It is not an axiom that the triple point is intrinsic to the material.  It comes from more basic physics.  Thus, one can explain why certain phenomena do or do not come into play when considering it.

Comment: @Colin: I agree with @Mark that it's by no means intrinsic to a single water molecule (or to what do you refer by *intrinsic*?). If you start with some model in statistical physics then you can (in principle) compute its triple point (or more generally multiple-phases coexistence points). But this will in general depend on all interactions between all parts of the system and triple point is a property of a complete system, not just one molecule. In particular, it's a property also of the external fields and the way they couple to the molecules.

Comment: @Marek @Mark: By intrinsic I mean it's a property of the material. It doesn't change due to ambient gravitational or other fields (unless we're talking about very strong fields which can distort atomic structures). As Greg P wrote, it does not depend on "all interactions between all parts of a system." If the water at the top of a tall tank is at its triple point, the water at the bottom of the tank doesn't care. All that matters is the local temp and pressure. Gravity or other affects may impact these variables, but they remain the only things which affect the triple point.

Comment: @Colin: I don't understand why temperature and pressure should be the only things that affect the triple point. Triple point is characterized geometrically as unique point where phases coexist. It doesn't matter whether you draw it on T-p diagram or p-V diagram or any other sort of diagram. Only thing that matters is what kind of couplings can change it. And it's not clear to me that gravitational coupling doesn't belong to those valid couplings. I can definitely imagine e.g. some lattice models whose phase properties *do depend* on the presence/absence of other interactions.

Comment: @marek: You could plot it any way you like, of course, but that doesn't mean it has any dependence on the variables you plot against. Various matter phases exist due to intra-molecular interaction, which is influenced by local parameters like temperature and pressure. Gravity can produce pressure, sure. But how is the interaction of a pair of molecules going to be changed by gravity directly? There is no reason to assume this interaction a priori. I guess I'm asking why you think gravity might matter when you don't think that, e.g., the color of my shoes would matter to the phase diagram.

Comment: @Colin: no, it's not only intramolecular interactions why phases exist but *any* interaction at all. It's easy to simulate two-point interactions by potentials in certain cases. Also, local interactions are surely not influenced by temperature and pressure. It's precisely the reverse: temperature and pressure are macroscopic effects arising from interactions. In any case, if you are saying gravitation doesn't matter here, you should explain why. Color of your shoes doesn't matter because it's not part of the problem at all; in big contrast to gravity ;-)

Comment: @Marek: Both are true: T and P are the result of intra-molecular interactions, and they also influence those interactions. Are you seriously claiming otherwise? Like my shoes, gravity isn't part of this problem at all. You're saying it is, so you should explain why. You'll have to deal with the fact that phase changes do not change gravitational potential, and the force due to gravity on a molecule is the same both before and after a phase change.

Comment: The point is that there is no need to start publishing phase diagrams with T, P, and g! A tank of water in gravity is a tank of water in which different points of the tank have different pressures.  g is not an additional quantity specifying the thermodynamic state.  If you think it is, then you also need to publish phase diagrams with T, p, g, and the height within the tank because the pressure will depend on height!

Comment: @Colin: Yes, I am claiming otherwise. How could temperature influence microscopic interactions? It only *describes* them, but definitely doesn't influence them. If temperature (and pressure) influences anything, it's other macroscopic properties like phase transitions and triple point. What do you mean gravity is not part of the problem? It's in the question's title, so if you think it's not, you'll have to convince me somehow.

Comment: @Greg: I don't agree at all! If the gravitational field is strong enough, it will also start to act locally as an attractive force. Because triple point arises as a consequence of statistics of huge number of molecules interacting by certain potential (say, Lennard-Jones), gravity will definitely change that potential and also the macroscopic properties (like triple point). You are probably talking just about weak gravity, and not arbitrary interaction though. So this is where our disagreement arises, I guess.

Comment: Oh, you mean the actual gravitational attraction between molecules! I didn't realize this question was that fancy. Then I agree.  Although as a Devil's advocate I could disagree and say that in a locally free-falling reference frame, even this very strong gravity does not look like a force ;-)

Comment: @Marek: No, an external gravitational field does not become an attractive force between the molecules. They feel the same inter-molecular forces regardless of external gravity. They do have some gravitational interaction with each other, however weak it is, but this is just a normal part of their inter-molecular interaction.

Comment: @Marek: Temperature is indeed descriptive of a material. It describes the average kinetic energy of the molecules. Clearly, molecules will interact differently when they encounter each other at different kinetic energy levels.

Comment: So is this question about an external gravity field changing the triple point, or is it about the role that gravity plays in intermolecular interactions? They are very different questions. Molecules have mass and therefore interact gravitationally, but an external field has no bearing on bulk properties like the triple point.

Comment: @Greg, @Colin: no, I didn't mean attractive gravitational potential between molecules, sorry for the confusion. What I meant is that the resulting macroscopic effects depend on all kinds of interactions, not just two-point ones. One-point (or external field) are as much as important as are three- and more-point interactions (although these are rarely encountered in mechanics) and in general any additional interaction changes the phase properties. I just don't understand why you a priori rule out gravity (which is one possible external force field).

Comment: @Colin: there's a long way between kinetic energy of a molecule and temperature. While the cross sections surely depend on the former, it's hard to say they depend on the latter. But in any case it's clear that individual molecule definitely doesn't feel any temperature. All it feels is other molecules and it feels them via microscopic interactions.

Comment: @Marek: In general, yes macroscopic effects on a system can be produced by any number of interactions, and in general you can't just rule out gravity. But this isn't about any macroscopic effect in general, this is just about phase change. That's a very specific property of a material! The phases of matter are the macroscopic result of intermolecular attraction, which is totally independent of external gravity. Which is another way of saying that phase transitions does not change gravitational potential.

Comment: The only exception may be in a case where gravity is strong enough to distort electron orbitals, but I don't think that's what you're asking about, is it?

Comment: @Marek: Wait, you just contradicted yourself. You admit (correctly) that interaction cross-sections depend on the kinetic energy of the molecules, but then deny that intermolecular interactions will be different in materials of differing temperature? I'm beginning to suspect that you may not yet have taken statistical mechanics/thermodynamics. I don't mean that as an insult, but you seem to be lacking some of the fundamentals of the topic. We use temperature as a descriptor precisely because it describes the average kinetic energy which is important in intermolecular interactions.

Comment: @Colin: I still don't follow. Take Ising model with two-point ferromagnetic interaction. If you'll put it into external field, it's phase properties will change. So if you are saying that certain external field is not important (and you are saying that) then you have to explain *why*. In all the answers around us and all the comments, I haven't seen a single explanation yet. People probably discard it as obvious. If so, it can't hurt to explain the reason clearly. Because I don't find it obvious at all.

Comment: @Marek, this is a matter of language.  I am biased toward thinking about bulk properties of matter (i.e. the triple point).  A gravitational field makes the water inhomogeneous, so that it is no longer represented by a single point in the T-p phase diagram.  It is not like an external magnetic field in an Ising model, which affects each spin in the same way! Anyway, we are straying from the actual question, which I believe has not been answered.

Comment: @Colin: "but then deny that intermolecular interactions will be different in materials of differing temperature?" -> yes, I do deny that! The interactions are still the same. Only the proportion of molecules undertaking the interaction at any given energy will change. But the interaction (e.g. electromagnetic one) is still the good old interaction and it definitely doesn't depend on temperature. By the way, I am also beginning to suspect that you haven't taken any statistical physics course. As for me, statistical physics is my primary area of research, so rest assured I took it ;-)

Comment: @Marek, to elaborate just a little more (although I think we basically agree on facts and are just arguing about semantics), the external field H in the Ising model is a good thermodynamic quantity because it does not affect different spatial locations in different ways.  Note that H is very much like pressure p in a liquid/gas.  Adding a gravitational field is like having a spatially varying H rather than a constant H.  Which is of course interesting, but it is not bulk thermodynamics - that is why the Ising phase diagram only has an H, not a spatially varying H.

Comment: @Greg: what do you mean an external field in Ising model affects each spin in a same way? You can choose a field that is an arbitrary function of position. And these general perturbations are much studied too. And they change the phase properties too (it's actually useful to ask, which of them *don't* and these correspond to additional symmetries in the system, like Zamolodchikov's $E_8$ at the critical point). So again: if you are saying gravitation is not changing the triple point, my question is *why*. And this is not straying from the question. It's actually the *very* question Mark asked.

Comment: @Marek: Maybe we have a problem of definitions, because I know you don't believe what you just said. To me, what you are saying is equivalent to claiming that water does not freeze, crystallization does not happen, chemical reactions do not happen faster at higher temperature, etc. Of course, all these things do happen, and they happen because of changes in the dynamics of molecular interactions as a function of temperature. I'd like to understand your definitions when you say that "The interactions are still the same" because a huge number of obvious phenomenon seem to say quite the opposite.

Comment: @Colin: obviously I am not saying water doesn't freeze so it's just you misinterpreting my statements and coming to wrong conclusions. Consider again Ising model for simplicity with just two-point ferromagnetic interaction. This interaction doesn't depend on the temperature at all. Whether you have $0K$ or $100K$ two like spins will always have lower energy than unlike spins by the same amount. What depends on the temperature are macroscopic properties like correlations and they depend on it by the usual prescription of $\exp(-\beta E)$. But individual interactions are *always* the same!

Comment: @Colin: no, I am indeed not talking about that strong gravity (although the question is interesting, but we might as well consider the water near extremely curved BH horizon). I am talking about the fact that *any* interaction whatsoever in general changes macroscopic properties of the system. If it doesn't, an explanation is in order (often it is some hidden symmetry, but this is not that case). So I'll be waiting for it.

Comment: @Marek: This is certainly a matter of language.  I have no doubt that it is interesting to ask what happens in the presence of an external field, and that is indeed the point of Mark's question (which we have not answered).  But when we talk about the thermodynamics properties of water, we mean the bulk properties.  I you don't agree, then I am content to forget that fact for the purposes of this discussion.  I think we should try to answer the question rather than arguing about whether spatially varying fields "change the triple point."

Comment: @Marek: That is true in the Ising model, but that is a model system that was built with no temperature dependence. In a real collection of molecules, the probability of a pair of molecules coalescing into a crystal is much higher at lower kinetic energy, and therefore a sample at lower temperature is much more likely to crystallize. Now take the same sample of material in a gravity field. The probability of a pair of atoms sticking together depends on how often molecules touch (pressure) and with how much energy they collide (temperature). How would gravity change this?

Comment: @Greg: I don't understand. Question asks if (and how) triple point changes in the present of external field. This is precisely what we are discussing. @Colin: no true microscopic system is built with temperature dependence. Temperature is purely macroscopic effect and has no say at microscopic scales. Every interaction is still the same, only probability with which those interactions occur changes. I guess we are saying the same thing with different words though.

Comment: @Greg, @Colin: in any case, I think discussion here is again getting quite hard to follow, so it would be great if you could join our chat room and discuss things over there. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/physics

Comment: @Marek: I don't want to argue any more about whether gravity 'changes the triple point of water.' Personally, I would not say that a gravitational field changes the triple point of water any more than I would say that an external magnetic field (spatially-varying or not) would change, say, the critical temperature of an Ising model.  The critical temperature is whatever it is.  The field will have various effects, including interesting effects on domain shapes, etc.  But feel free to say that the triple point changes, and I will understand what you mean.

Comment: @Greg: I don't understand you at all. The field can of course change the critical temperature and not only that, it can change critical behavior! And why don't you want to discuss the dependence of the triple point of water? Read the question's title -- it asks precisely for that kind of discussion. Why did you provide an answer in the first place, if you don't want to discuss these matters, then?

Comment: @Marek: I think you understand what I mean when I say that the critical temperature of a particular Ising model is whatever it is (2.269 or whatever for the square lattice 2D model), and that adding an external field moves us around in the phase diagram but does not change the critical temperature.  I understand that you might view that external field, instead, as another parameter of the model itself, in which case, fine. This is a trivial semantic issue.  As for the title of the question, my whole point was that it was ill-posed.

Comment: @Greg: perhaps our disagreement is indeed purely semantic but I can't say I understand you now. Do you agree with that changing an external field can move the critical point (or triple point) of a given model (where precise model is understood to depend also on external field)? If so, why are you saying that OP's question is ill-posed? It's asking for precisely this: will the triple point depend on the additional external field? And your answer seems to be that in general it does. Or am I missing something? By the way, the discussion in the chat room would definitely be better...

Comment: @Marek: Sorry, chat doesn't seem to work. I think our disagreement might stem from emphasizing lattice models vs. speaking about the properties of water.  As you say, if the definition of the model depends on the external fields, then the external fields affect the phase diagram. But when most people (not mathematical physicists!) speak of water, they do not include external gravitational fields in the 'definition' of the substance itself.  There is only one phase diagram of water, whether we are in space or on Mars!

Comment: I would like to pursue this approach, which addresses the effect of gravity on two-phase coexistence: http://web.ist.utl.pt/berberan/data/79.pdf  Note that they do not talk about gravity "changing the saturation pressure" at a given temperature! The phase diagram of, say, the Van der Waals equation of state is still the same.  However, now we must take into account the fact that different locations have different pressures (hence different densities).  The 3-phase situation will be even more complicated, of course!

Comment: @Greg: ah, okay then. I was not aware about this point of view (and I guess it can be useful sometimes). I am indeed used to consider every interaction part of the model itself. But with this point being understood, I think OP's question does make sense. He's just asking how does the triple point of the model [water + gravity] look like and this should definitely depend not only properties of water but also on the properties of gravity. And if not, one should explain why it doesn't (it's possible that the explanation is quite trivial, but it should be still stated).

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [mpq](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/how-does-the-temperature-of-the-triple-point-of-water-depend-on-gravitational-acc/2294#2294) and [Greg's remarks](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/how-does-the-temperature-of-the-triple-point-of-water-depend-on-gravitational-acc/2303#2303).

A triple point is a unique (pressure,temperature) pair for each material (and where appropriate group of phases) where three phases of matter can coexist in equilibrium.

If you are not at the right pressure, there is *no* temperature where this occurs, and if you are not at the right temperature there is *no* pressure where this occurs.

In that sense the question is simply based on a misconception.

---

Several posters have tried to address the effects of changing gravitation on the locally experienced pressure due to a atmosphere column. That's fine as far as it goes, but it doesn't really go to the question.

Diddling the local gravity will change the pressure naturally experienced due the local atmosphere but *will not* affect the parameters of the triple point.

Comment: If I assume the normal sort of geometry, the gas phase will be upgravity of the liquid and solid phases. I think this means that we can include the extra gravitational potential energy of the gas molecules to about a mean free path, as Mark wants to. This wouldn't be much, as a MFP is going to be rather small (at least for say water/steam) probably only a few microns. But I'm not even sure if that is right, does the potential a mean free path above the liquid/gas interface matter, or just the potential right at the interface? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference; phase transitions does not change gravitational potential.

Comment: What kind of answer is this?

Comment: @Marek Concise (-;

Comment: This answer is simply wrong I'm afraid. The gravitational potential affects the internal pressure of the fluid, and thus the triple point temperature.

Comment: Changing the pressure also affects the pressure ;-) Do we then say that changing the pressure therefore affects the 'pressure of the triple point'? The question itself does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Noldorin: You might want to look again at the meaning of "triple point". It is usually defined as the point in the P-T plane where three phases can co-exist. Note that that is a fixed pressure and a fixed temperature. Changing the gas pressure does *not* change where the triple point is. Merely whether you need a pressure vessel to achieve it. To elaborate you can't get water vapor, liquid water and ice I to coexist in equilibrium at 1 atmosphere because the triple point occurs at a much lower pressure. Period.

Comment: @Noldorin My answer is perfectly correct -- it was meant to show that the question is wrong. The grav. force acting on a particle does not depend on its motion; the question suggest that the substance start to levitate after evaporation or (even worse) is automatically scattered uniformly over the container volume.

Comment: Oops; seems I may be wrong indeed. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to derive triple point directly, but let me talk about something similar and see where it leads.

For ideal gas atmosphere you'll find out that $g$ works as an inverse temperature. That is, $0K$ is the same as infinitely strong gravity because both keep the gas at the ground.

The real gases exhibit phase transitions, so we should promote ideal gas to something like van der Waals gas. This should not change the above correspondence of $\beta = {1 \over k_B T}$ and $g$ much. Therefore, I would imagine that one would get a phase transition at high $g$ with constant $\beta$. Or in other words, that in the presence of gravitational field, higher temperatures are enough for the phase transition. Or in other words yet, we have another coupling $g$ that tells system to cluster besides the usual thermal coupling $\beta$.

Now, this carries over (by a huge and completely unjustified extrapolation) to the triple point of water. I'll try to provide some calculations later.

Comment: excuse my ignorance - what is $\beta$?

Comment: @Mark: sorry, I didn't realize this wasn't universally known. I'll edit the info into my answer.

Comment: How can g have the same effect as a change in temperature? It has a position-dependent effect.  In a gravitational field, the density will depend on location - in contrast to the situation with a different temperature.

Comment: @Greg: I think Marek is getting at the idea that the [scale height](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/PressureScaleHeight.html) of an atmosphere can be changed by dialing either the gravity or the temperature. Which is true but beside the point.

Comment: @dmckee: yes, that's what I was getting at, but I realize now that I missed the point completely.

Answer (score 0):

Back of the envelope calculation:

- gravity will manifest itself by increasing the pressure by a factor of $mg/A$ where A is the surface of the container with water at the triple point. So basically the effect is shifting the triple point [phase diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPhase-diag2.svg) down. So the triple point would be at the same temperature with a lower pressure.

$$p_{measured} = p_{gas} + p_{gravity}$$

- Assuming a regular shape we can say that $p_{gravity}=\rho g h$ where $\rho$ is the density of the gas at our triple point pressure and h is the typical height of a column of gas.

$$p_{gravity}=\rho g h$$

- to calculate $\rho$ we can use the ideal gas law:

$$\rho = \frac{Nm_w}{V} = \frac{p_{gas}m_w}{kT}$$

- we can now calculate what fraction of pressure is due to gravity

$$\frac{p_{gravity}}{p_{gas}}=\rho g h/p_{gas}=\frac{m_w g h}{kT}$$

- using the following values we can calculate this ratio

$m_w = 3 \times 10^{-26} \mathrm{kg}$

$g = 9.81 \mathrm{m/s^{2}}$

$h = 1 \mathrm{m}$

$k = 1.38 \times 10^{-23} \mathrm{J/K}$

$T = 273.16 K$

$$\frac{p_{gravity}}{p_{gas}}=0.000078$$

This means that you need a value for g one thousand times stronger to see a large effect.

Comment: A bigger value of g, or a container a kilometer high...

Comment: The kilometre high container would need to have constant pressure though.

Comment: If $T$ was lowered though, you'd see a bigger change. Nice calculation !

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on what you mean by $p_{gas}$ and $p_{gravity}$? My immediate instinct is the call shenanigans, but I'm willing to be convinced that I've missed something.

Comment: To expand on my comment, I think you might be re-inventing the distinction between [gauge pressure and absolute pressure](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-gauge-pressure-and-absolute-pressure/).

Comment: @dmckee: I am only talking about absolute pressure. This has two components corresponding to two components of the motions of the molecules (so to say), the normal chaotic motion and the downwards accelerated motion due to gravity. The second is normally not considered - as I've shown it's a really small component.